# Use of Spring Framework for RabbitMQ is reducing the performance

Tags: spring, rabbitmq

I have created a producer, which was using `com.rabbitmq.client.connectionFactory` and was sending 1,000,000 messages (40 Bytes) in 100 seconds.

But now I want an spring abstraction. I was unable to use `com.rabbitmq.client.connectionFactory` rather I had to use `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.SingleConnectionFactory`. Using this connection factory only 100,000 messages (40 Bytes) are send to the broker in 100 seconds.

Does anybody have experience why the performance is reduced so much (around 90%).

The code using "import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;" is ->

```
package Multiple_queues_multiple_consumers;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.rabbitmq.client.AMQP;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
public class Producer {
    private static Connection myConnection;
    private static Channel myChannel;
    public static String myQueueName;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        long startTime=0;
        int count=0;
        ConnectionFactory myFactory=new ConnectionFactory();
        myFactory.setHost("localhost");
        try {
            myConnection = myFactory.newConnection();
            myChannel = myConnection.createChannel();
            String myExchange = "wxyzabc";
            String myBody = "This is a message : message numberxxxxxx";
            String myRoutingKey = "RoutingKey";
            myQueueName = "new_Queue";
            myChannel.exchangeDeclare(myExchange, "direct", true, false, null);
            myChannel.queueDeclare(myQueueName, true, false, false, null);
            myChannel.queueBind(myQueueName, myExchange, myRoutingKey);
            startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
            AMQP.BasicProperties properties = new AMQP.BasicProperties();
            properties.setDeliveryMode(2);
            startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
            while(count++<=10000){
                myChannel.basicPublish(myExchange, myRoutingKey, true, true, properties, myBody.getBytes() );
            }
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime);
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

The code using SpringFramework is :->

Producer1.java

```
import org.springframework.amqp.core.AmqpAdmin;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Binding;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.DirectExchange;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Message;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
public class Producer1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new         ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Producer1.xml");
    AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin = context.getBean(RabbitAdmin.class);
    Queue queue = new Queue("sampleQueue");
    DirectExchange exchange = new DirectExchange("myExchange");
    Binding binding = new Binding(queue, exchange, "");
    amqpAdmin.declareQueue(queue);
    amqpAdmin.declareExchange(exchange);
    amqpAdmin.declareBinding(binding);
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = context.getBean(RabbitTemplate.class);
    String routingKey = "";
    String myBody = "This is a message : message numberxxxxxx";
    Message Msg = new Message(myBody.getBytes(), null);
    int count=0;
    long CurrTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(count++<=10000){
        rabbitTemplate.send(routingKey, Msg);
        //System.out.println("Message Sent");
    }
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()-CurrTime);
}
}
```

Producer1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


<!-- Define a connectionFactory -->
<bean id="rabbitConnectionFactory" class="com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory">
<property name="host" value="localhost" />
</bean>

<bean id="connectionFactory"         class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.SingleConnectionFactory">
<constructor-arg ref="rabbitConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>

<!-- Tell the Admin bean about that connectionFactory and initialize it, create a     queue and an exchange on Rabbit Broker using the RabbitTemplate provided by Spring framework-Rabbit APIs -->
<bean id="Admin" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin">
<constructor-arg ref="connectionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="rabbitTemplate" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate"
p:connectionFactory-ref="connectionFactory"
p:routingKey="myRoutingKey"
p:exchange="myExchange" />

</beans>
```

Comment: does the previous connectionFactory create more than one connection?

Comment: No, no settings are changed in both the implementations.
There is only 1 exchange and 1 queue and the binding used is direct.

Comment: you either measured it incorrectly or in fact there were more than 1 connections used in the first case, such difference in performance is impossible.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by 'i was unable to use'? can you post some config files/logs?

Comment: I THOUGHT SOMEBODY WILL COME TO HELP ME... but... :(
This was my first post and nobody helped me..is there something more which you needed or what, why nobody is willing to help.
If ur so sure that performance must not get down, then please tell me the reason why its happening in my case. I've posted the codes used by me. 
Any help is warmly welcome.
Thanks,
Gurpreet Singh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<!-- Define a connectionFactory -->
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="com.rabbitmq.client.connectionFactory">
<constructor-arg value="localhost" />
<property name="username" value="guest" />
<property name="password" value="guest" />
</bean>

<bean id="Admin" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin">
<constructor-arg ref="connectionFactory" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

Using this xml file, the error appears saying org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin could not cast com.rabbitmq.client.connectionFactory for connectionfactory bean. 
The exact error is: "nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory] to required type [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found" .

Hence i have to use bean:

```
<bean id="connectionFactory"
class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.SingleConnectionFactory">
</bean>
```

Comment: Also now I am getting something very interesting the time taken to send same number of message with different message size is same. It is around 13,000 ms for sending 10,000 message of sizes varying from 40 bytes to 40 KB.

Comment: Oh!!! This happens only when i use template.convertandSend option using template.send , it takes the much high time...

Comment: The above XML file is not exactly correct. Use of "org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory" as a class for connection factory is making it run as expected.

Comment: I have got one more thing that using CachingConnectionFactory is better in performance as compared to SimpleConnectionFactory. Though there is not very large change in throughput yet there is some...

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you used the same Rabbit MQ broker? Could you be using a broker on a different server, or an upgraded/downgraded version of RabbitMQ?

The other thing to look at is your jvm. Is it possible that you don't have enough memory configured and now the garbage collector is thrashing? Run `top` and see if the jvm's memory usage is close to the configured memory size.

Are you using an old version of RabbitMQ. Lots of Linux distros include RabbitMQ 1.7.2 which is an old version that has problems with large numbers of messages. Large is hard to define because it depends on your RAM, but RabbitMQ does not like to use more than 40% of RAM because it needs to copy a persistence transaction log in order to process it and clean it for log rollover. This can cause RabbitMQ to crash, and, of course, processing the huge logs will slow it down. RabbitMQ 2.4.1 handles the persister logs much better, in smaller chunks, and it also has much, much faster message routing code.

This still sounds to me like a Java problem, either Spring is just a pig and is terribly inefficient, or you have not given your jvm enough RAM to avoid frequent gc runs. What setting are you using for -Xmx?

Comment: Yup I've used the same Broker running on the same machine.
I've checked the code several times just for sending 10,000 continuous messages the direct use of "import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;" is taking around 1500ms whilst the use of springFramework using:<bean id="connectionFactory"
class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.SingleConnectionFactory">
</bean> takes around 10,000ms.

Comment: I found 1 interesting thing, that if I make 10.000 threads and then send one message using each thread then the time taken in sending these 10,000 messages is reduced from 10,000ms to 4,000ms(approx.)....

Comment: @ michael. Now I have  re installed the rabbitmq setup everthing must be fine now, because memory usage must not be problem at all now. But unfortunately I have not attained any success. Please HELP.